# authenticate and chatting in facebook using xmpp protocol

Tags: android

i am working on android application in which i m intergrating facebook in that i have to get online friend list and chat with the selected friend.write now i am using xampp protocol.in that i am not able to logiin with my email id as well as username.i am using the following code .....please somebudy help me to overcome this problem.....please solve this problem and please give me some steps to make this application send me on my email id:imvishalbhut@gmail.com

download from here:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68334633/fbchat.rar

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure, But can you try by logging in to your FB account and clicking on the below link

https://www.facebook.com/username

will take you to the creation of username. and then try to use that with your code.